# Parameter coming with null value does not change when I change it in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure as shown below; when I pass `NULL` for `Gkol` I want it to be changed to the minimum possible amount (that exists in the table), but it does not happen - why is that?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_vUnitsUnitTejariGetFilteredUnitDetail
    (@UnitFB BIT,
     @UnitWithCooking BIT,
     @MMofidFrom FLOAT = NULL,
     @MMofidTo FLOAT = NULL,
     @GKolFrom FLOAT = NULL,
     @GKolTo FLOAT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MMofidCalculative BIT
    DECLARE @GKolCalculative BIT

    IF (@MMofidFrom IS NULL)
        SELECT @MMofidFrom = MIN(MMofid) 
        FROM vw_PSA_UnitsUnitTejari

    IF (@MMofidTo IS NULL)
        SELECT @MMofidTo = MAX(MMofid) 
        FROM vw_PSA_UnitsUnitTejari

    IF (@GKolFrom IS NULL)
        SELECT @GKolFrom = MIN(GKol) 
        FROM vw_PSA_UnitsUnitTejari

    IF (@GKolTo IS NOT NULL)
        SELECT @GKolTo = MAX(GKol) 
        FROM vw_PSA_UnitsUnitTejari

    SELECT * 
    FROM vw_PSA_UnitsUnitTejari 
    WHERE UnitTypeID = 1
      AND UnitStateID = 1
      AND UnitFB = ISNULL(@UnitFB, UnitFB)
      AND UnitWithCooking = ISNULL(@UnitWithCooking, UnitWithCooking)
      AND MMofid BETWEEN @MMofidFrom AND @MMofidTo
      AND GKol BETWEEN @GKolFrom AND @GKolTo
END
```

Comment: Did you get error or wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it was not working, the problem was in the last if block

```
if(@GKolTo is not null)
```

I removed NOT and everything went well, thanks everyone